# ¿Cómo guardar en una variable php, el valor de un input de correo que se obtiene con javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel-5, funciones, input

Tengo un **input** de correo del cual obtengo su valor con **javascript** y necesito guardarlo en una variable **php** para poder pasarsela por parámetro a una función en **php**.

Esto es lo que he intentado y no funciona:

```
<?php $correo ?> = $('#email').val ();
```

Comment: ¿y el código? por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código correspondiente como texto (no como imagen), tanto html, como js y php.

Comment: Esto es lo que estoy intentando hacer y no func <?php $correo ?> = $('#email').val ();

Comment: Es decir esa variable que obtienes con javascript deseas pasar a otro archivo "php" y asignarlo a una variable ?

Answer (score 2):

No puedes pasar variables javascript a PHP, PHP corre del lado del servidor y no tiene por qué saber nada del lado del cliente.
Para poder obtener una variable javascript en PHP debes enviarle el valor de la variable a través de por ejemplo un formulario, o utilizando ajax, a través de métodos POST o GET.

HTML:

```
<html>
<form action="accion.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Guardar">
</form>
</html>
```

PHP (accion.php):

```
<?php
$valor = $_POST["mail"];
echo $valor; 
// el valor
?>
```